# Powershell change date format based on regex

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use a regex to find dates in a csv file and change the formatting because there are over 200 columns in this csv; manual column mapping for each date is not possible.

what I had previously was the following

```
$sf = '\\path\dept\Extracts\Date_Modified.csv'
$regex = "\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}"

(Get-Content $sf) | 
Foreach-Object {$_ -replace $regex, (get-date -f "yyyy-MM-dd") } | 
Set-Content $sf
```

that works fine if I want to replace all the dates with the current date, but that wasn't my goal.  my goal is to recognize human entry type dates (mm/dd/yyyy) and change them to yyyy-mm-dd that the database table is expecting when I load the csv.

how can I modify this?  or is there a better way to recognize date formats and change the format?

Comment: Use capture groups: `-replace '(\d{1,2})/(\d{1,2})/(\d{4})', '$3-$1-$2'`

Comment: Can you please put that as an answer so I can mark it correct?  just one quick ? I noticed I can't assign the regex to a variable and use it, I have to hard code it (which is fine too); can you tell me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer: use capture groups.  I don't know why you wouldn't be able to assign the regex to a variable before use (as I have done many times):

```
$sf = '\\path\dept\Extracts\Date_Modified.csv'
$regex = '(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})'

@(Get-Content -Path $sf) | 
    ForEach-Object { $_ -replace $regex, '$3-$1-$2' } | 
    Set-Content -Path $sf
```

Of special note, use single-quotes in the replace statement so you don't end up trying to interpolate `$1` into a (presumably null) variable.